# how to set the rights for placeholder ribbon

Tags: sitecore

beginner question for sitecore about settings the right.
So I have an item is open in the page editor. 
The renderings on the page has bunch of icons on the ribbon. One of them called 'select the parent element (element name)'.
In my case when I click on it, I am presented with the placeholder with button  'add here' and the ribbon with some component buttons that a user can use to add the controls.

So, QUESTION:

"how I add access to the button on that ribbon for certain role? Where do I set it up? "
For some certain role that placeholder's ribbon is completely empty, including there is no button 'select the parent element' even though
i know there is a parent element.

thank you very much for help,
HF

Here are the screenshots (no icons on the placeholder ribbon, and the user's rights:
enter image description here[image]

[image]

And here is how that looks for the admin:
[image]

Comment: Is the user (or your role) a member of the Sitecore Client Designing role? Best to add them to Sitecore\Designer and Sitecore\Author as well if they need content editing access as well: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/61/security_reference-a4.pdf

Comment: as you can see from the screenshot above, the user is a member of both Designer, Author (Designer inherits Sitecore Client Designing role) - last on the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

All the settings for the Page Editor are held in the Core database. So in the Sitecore Desktop, switch to the core database and open up the Content Editor.

Navigate to : `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit`

This item holds the items that make up the page editor. To edit the ribbon menues, go to:

> /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons

[image: Core Tree]

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for answering.

I am looking at that location, and i can't find the button called 'select the parent element' (blue arrow). Is it in the same location?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember seeing that particular button in the Core database, so this is likely a built-in feature that requires the user to have one of the built-in permissions.

The first thing I would check is that Designing is turned on. Have the user go to the 'View' tab in Page Editor and make sure they have checked the 'Designing' checkbox.

If that doesn't work, it sounds like the user you have does not have design access to the page. I would examine the inherited roles using the User Manager and check if they have the Sitecore Designer role inherited.

It is possible they just need to be provided the correct role in the system so that they can access the buttons.

Comment: yes, I checked if 'Designing' checkbox is checked. and it is checked. Also the user has the role 'Designer'..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "Sitecore Client developing role"? 
Also, for the blue arrow drop list location, in order for the rendering button to show up in that location, you have to check whether the button in the webedit folder under core database(/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Default Rendering Buttons).  The Type field needs to be "Common" in order to show up in the blue arrow droplist.

Example can be the "Edit related item" (/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Default Rendering Buttons/Edit related item) shows up in the blue arrow droplist.

Comment: if I add ' Sitecore Client Developing role', then i have all the hierarchy shown..  So there is something with the permissions that i dont' know how to set.